# System of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have some problems solving a system in mathematica.

```
dX/dt = p * ( (S * X) / (S + k) ) - alfa * X
dS/dt = alfa * ( S(i) - S) - (p / y)*((S * X) / (S + k) )
```

I have to write a linear aproximation for this system for S>>k ( S is much larger than k ) then to solve the aproximated system and use the solution for 
X and the data that I have in a table to obtain a numerical value for p. I have to plot the logarithm of X against the time, and estimate the slope.

How can I write a linear aproximation of a system in mathematica?

And then in my table I have several values for S, how can I retrive all values, then solve the equations for each value?

Comment: Looks like one of my favorite ecological models, growth of a consumer `X` on a resource `S` in a chemostat.  If you assume `S>>k`, then you don't need the second equation and the functional response `S/(S+k)` is approximately 1.  Then the equation for `X'[t]` simplifies to `X'[t]==(p-alfa)*X[t]`, which is the (linear) model for exponential growth, with solution `X[t]==X[0]*E^((p-alfa)*t`.  Taking logs, `Log[X[t]]==Log[X[0]]+(p-alfa)*t`.  Find the slope by applying `LinearModelFit` to your data.

Comment: [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) should be useful; [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html) might come in handy, too; for solving you'll need [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and for plotting, probably [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

Comment: What is `S(i)` meant to be?  Mathematica interprets it as `S*i`, but that may not be what you want.

Comment: @ChrisK I forgot to say alfa=0 in my case. I did the computations in mathematica but it gives me an error at solving the system part `eq1 = x'[t] == (p*s*x[t])/(s + k) - alfa*x[t]` 
`eq1Aprox = x'[t] == (p*s*x[t])/s - alfa*x[t]` 
`eq2 = s'[t] == alfa*(si - s[t]) - (p/y)*((s[t]*x)/(s[t] + k))` 
`eq2Aprox = s'[t] == alfa*(si - s[t]) - (p/y)*((s[t]*x)/s[t])` 
`alfa := 0` 
`sol1 = DSolve[eq1Aprox, x[t], t]` 
`sol2 = DSolve[eq2Aprox, s[t], t]` 
`solSystem = DSolve[{eq1Aprox,eq2Aprox}, {x, s}, t]` 
it says The function x has no arguments.

Comment: @ChrisK Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/g0VOXR at what I did, and here is a screenshot to the problem https://ibb.co/de7WK6, I really apreciate your help

Comment: @bbgodfrey s(i) is the input concentration, from the table that I have. In the comment above I put a screenshot to the problem

Comment: It is a common error for people to write x' or x when Mathematica is expecting x'[t] and x[t] in every case. So replace your two "bare" x with x[t] and use semicolon at the end of every line to avoid a little confusion and you should then get {s->Function[{t},C[1]-((-1+E^(p t)) C[2])/y], 
 x->Function[{t},E^(p t)C[2]]}

Comment: @Bill I did what you said and now it's ok. But now how can I use the solution for x from the system and the data from my table to obtain a numerical value for p? I don't understand this part: `Plot the logarithm of 
X against the time, and estimate the slope. ` My table is a matrix `{ time, s, x}` and I have 53 rows. I did something `ListLogLinearPlot[{data[[1, 3 ;; 53, 3]], data[[1, 3 ;; 53, 1]]}, 
 Joined -> True]` but it gives me only a graph

Comment: As I wrote above, the linearized solution is `Log[X[t]]==Log[X[0]]+p*t`. Use `LinearModelFit` to fit your (logged) data to a line, `p` is the slope.

Comment: @ChrisK sorry, but I really don't understant, help please. Let's say my first 2 data from my table are: {`t=0;` `s=45.84;` `x=0.15`} and then { `t=0.15;` `s=45.29;` `x=0.19;` } . How can i use these values and the equation `Log[x[t]] == Log[x[0]] + p*t` to determine values for `p`?